# How to divide all possible 3-digit codes into 4 groups

Tags: combinatorics

3 characters (numerical digits, letters, images, etc) are chosen from a set of 10, without replacement.

There are 120 such codes, with each character appearing 36 times.
ie. ABC, ABD, ABE, ... , GHI, GIJ, HIJ

How can these codes be put into four groups, so that each character appears 9 times in each group?

Comment: Did you try to solve this question? Where did you get stuck?

Answer (score 0):

This can easily be break into 12 subgroups. (each letter appear 3 times in each group)

SubGroup1: ABC, BCD, CDE, DEF, ....

SubGroup2: ABD, BCE, CDF, DEG, ....

SubSubGroup3: ABE, ......

SubGroup4: ABF, ......

SubGroup5: ABG, .......

SubGroup6: ABH, .......

SubGroup7: ABI, .......

SubGroup8: ACE, BDF, ......

SubGroup9: ACF, BDG, ......

SubGroup10: ACG, .......

SubGroup11: ACH, ....

SubGroup12: ADG, ...

any combination of 4 subgroups in each group will give you a grouping you wanted